# If the column is empty, select the same column using different where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to select rpd.name using a different WHERE clause if the previous one returns an empty string?

I've looked into CASE, but I'm not sure how would I go about using it.

### table replacement_part

**part_id** **href**
1  url_1
2  url_2
3  url_3

### table replacement_part_description

**part_id** **language_id**  **name**
1   2  
1   1   hose
2   2  
2   1   control module
3   2   vonkajsi kryt
3   1   outer casing

### expected output

**part_id** **href** **name**
1  url_1   hose
2  url_2   control module
3  url_3   vonkajsi kryt

```
SELECT *
FROM replacement_part AS rp
LEFT JOIN  replacement_part_description AS rpd
    ON (rp.part_id = rpd.part_id)
WHERE language_id = :id
```

So something like

```
if rpd.name = ''
    WHERE language_id = a,
else
    WHERE language_id = b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to join the rpd table twice, moving the where clause on the ON condition, and then use COALESCE:

```
SELECT
  ...,
  COALESCE(rpd1.name, rpd2.name) AS name
FROM
  replacement_part rp LEFT JOIN replacement_part_description rpd1
  ON rp.part_id = rpd1.part_id AND rpd1.language=a
  LEFT JOIN replacement_part_description rpd2
  ON rp.part_id = prd2.part_id AND rpd2.language=b
```

here I suppose that the language is on the description table. If name is an empty string, instead of coalesce you could use CASE WHEN:

```
CASE WHEN rpd1.name='' OR rpd1.name IS NULL THEN rpd2.name ELSE rpd1.name END AS Name
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working - I'm only getting names from one language, the ones from the other are empty

Answer (score 1):

This ?

```
SELECT *
FROM replacement_part AS rp
LEFT JOIN  replacement_part_description AS rpd
    ON (rp.part_id = rpd.part_id)
WHERE 
    (
        language_id = :id 
        AND (rpd.name = '' OR rpd.name IS NULL)
    )
    OR language_id = b
```

Comment: your field is NULL or empty string ? (not the same)

Comment: @PeterAbsolon update; BTW can you add some data to work with and the expected result ?

Comment: My field is an empty string.

Comment: @PeterAbsolon is the new request better ? have you got some data, because it seem I don't understand what you want...

Comment: Doesn't work either. I've updated my original question with data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by` and `limit` to get one row with priorities:

```
select . . .
from . . .
where (language_id = a and rpd.name = '') or
      language_id = b
order by (language_id = a) desc -- put the "a" rows first
limit 1;
```